# Subtracting VAT from a number in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am beginner in JS and this code

```js
$('.brutto_amount').each(function (index, value) {
    let amount = $(this).text().replace(' brutto / rok', '').replace('(', ''); console.log(amount);
    if (discountType == 0) {
        let newAmount = (amount - discountValue).toFixed(2);
        if(newAmount < 0) newAmount = 1;
        $(this).html(`${newAmount} brutto / rok `);
    } else if (discountType == 1) {
        let newAmount = (amount - ((parseInt(amount) * parseInt(discountValue)) / 100)).toFixed(2);
        if(newAmount < 0) newAmount = 1;
        $(this).html(`${newAmount} brutto / rok `);
    }
});
```

works fine so far.

How can I subtract 23% VAT from the variable `newAmount` and round it to 2 decimal places?

Comment: The first is a simple math problem, if your `newAmount` value is a brutto value, calculating the netto, with a vat of 23%, is as simple as `newAmount / 123 * 100`. Use `calculatedNetto.toFixed(2)` to round that to 2 numbers. Be aware though, that calculations in JS will have rounding errors due to floating point precision. For further information about the issue and how to circumvent that, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem similar to what  Lapskaus mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63413552/subtracting-vat-from-a-number-in-javascript/63413975#comment112132192_63413552):

> The first is a simple math problem, if your `newAmount` value is a brutto value, calculating the netto, with a vat of 23%, is as simple as `newAmount / 123 * 100`. Use `calculatedNetto.toFixed(2)` to round that to 2 numbers. Be aware though, that calculations in JS will have rounding errors due to floating point precision. For further information about the issue and how to circumvent that, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript). newAmount will be a brutto value which will be 123% from which you want to calculate the 100% value. You substract 23% off of 123 which is too much

Comment: newAmount will be a brutto value which will be 123% from which you want to calculate the 100% value. You substract 23% off of 123 which is too much